# error: no template named 'optional' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'folly::Optional'

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

getting this error while compiling on ios device OS 13 plus. i upgraded the react-native project  "react-native": "0.63.4" to  "react-native": "^0.72.4" and upgraded some libraries as-well and getting this error. can anyone help me in this please.

i upgraded the project and upgraded the libraries which were required and run on ios so getting this error

here is my package json file:

```
{
  "name": "Flakex",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.1",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.12.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.32.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^4.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.72.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-awesome-card-io": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.1292.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^6.0.5",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input-view": "^0.0.7",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.10",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.2.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.28.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "https://github.com/noway/react-native-material-dropdown",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.0.16",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "rn-faded-scrollview": "^1.0.10",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.65.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4522

Comment: you have just need to run `cd ios/ && pod update`

Answer (score 5):

Its an issue with react-native-reanimated v2

you need to upgrade it to the latest version (3.5.4 currently)

Comment: yes i updated the liberary and worked for me...  Thanks for the solution